# Laravel white page loading route

Tags: laravel, view, routes

I had a `login.blade.php` with some code, and I decided to replace with a new one.
I renamed it to `old_login.blade.php` and create a new file, in the same path, with the name `login.blade.php`.

After a while, I decided to rollback to my old login page.
I delete `login.blade.php`, and renamed the `old_login.blad.php` with the original name to return back.
No code was edited, only views.

The problem is that the page returned a blanck white page with many comments (the comment's tag is not closed).

I try to make a copy of the view, called `test.blade.php`, and change the route to that view. It diplay them correctly. But If I change another time route to `myapp.login` to display `login.blade.php` view, it won't work.

I try anything but nothing is changed. I'm using laravel 5.1.

The code insiede my routes.php is

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('myapp.login');
});
```

the code inside the login.blade.php (same ad test.blade.php) is:

```
@extends("app")

@section("content")



{!! Form::open(["url" => "home"]) !!}
     <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("username", "Username:") !!}
        {!!Form::text("usr_username", "Luca", ["class" => "form-control"]) !!}
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label("password", "Password:") !!}
        {!!Form::input("password", "usr_password", "mypass", ["class" => "form-control"]) !!}
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::submit("Login", ["class" => "btn-primary form-control"]) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

@include("errors.list")
@stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a nonsense answer to resolve my problem: I cutted the code inside `login.blade.php`, save file, pasted it, and saved another time. Now it display correctly.